# Vapor 3 - send a HTTPRequest

Tags: vapor, server-side-swift

How do you send an API request in Vapor 3 with the `HTTPRequest` struct?

I tried variations of the following code..

```
var headers: HTTPHeaders = .init()
let body = HTTPBody(string: a)            
let httpReq = HTTPRequest(
    method: .POST,
    url: URL(string: "/post")!,
    headers: headers,
    body: body)

let httpRes: EventLoopFuture<HTTPResponse> = HTTPClient.connect(hostname: "httpbin.org", on: req).map(to: HTTPResponse.self) { client in
    return client.send(httpReq)
}
```

The compile error `Cannot convert value of type '(HTTPClient) -> EventLoopFuture<HTTPResponse>' to expected argument type '(HTTPClient) -> _'`

I have tried other variations of code that worked.

[Vapor 3 Beta Example Endpoint Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589415/vapor-3-beta-example-endpoint-request)

```
let client = try req.make(Client.self)

let response: Future<Response> = client.get("http://example.vapor.codes/json")
```

I read and re-read:

- https://api.vapor.codes/http/latest/HTTP/Structs/HTTPRequest.html
- https://api.vapor.codes/http/latest/HTTP/Classes/HTTPClient.html
- https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/http/client/

Comment: *I have tried other variations of code that worked* - so you got it working some way but want to use `HTTPRequest` instead?

Comment: hey @LinusGeffarth. I found a simpler way by using the higher level wrapper named `Client`.  I found the comments for this `Protocol` were inside the code file of `Client.swift` very helpful.

Comment: For my future self (and anyone else): you need to do `req.client().post(....)`, see docs in `Client.swift`, like rustyMagnet described above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is `.map(to: HTTPResponse.self)`. Map needs to transform its result into a new result regularly, like you would `map` an array. However, the result of your map-closure returns an `EventLoopFuture<HTTPResponse>`. This results in your `map` function returning an `EventLoopFuture<EventLoopFuture<HTTPResponse>>`.

To avoid this complexity, use `flatMap`.

```swift
var headers: HTTPHeaders = .init()
let body = HTTPBody(string: a)            
let httpReq = HTTPRequest(
    method: .POST,
    url: URL(string: "/post")!,
    headers: headers,
    body: body)

let client = HTTPClient.connect(hostname: "httpbin.org", on: req)

let httpRes = client.flatMap(to: HTTPResponse.self) { client in
    return client.send(httpReq)
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to use the Content APIs you can do so like this:

```swift
let data = httpRes.flatMap(to: ExampleData.self) { httpResponse in
    let response = Response(http: httpResponse, using: req)
    return try response.content.decode(ExampleData.self)
}
```

Comment: Really nice @JoannisO. How do you access the actual content of the response and transform the `Future<Response>` to `Future<ExampleData>`?  Reference to your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589415/vapor-3-beta-example-endpoint-request ? I can't seem to access `response.content.decode` using that style.

Comment: That's right, because you're using more low level APIs. HTTPResponse is the raw representation of a response. The Vapor "Content" APIs are a high level API. So you'll need to use the high level Vapor Client APIs to get access to these features.

However, if you insist on using the lower level HTTPClient, you can do that. See my update in the post.

Comment: Thanks @JoannisO. Works perfectly. I noticed you put your `Worker` as `app`.  Was that a mistake?  Or am I mistaken by using `req`?

Comment: @rustyMagnet yes, that was a mistake on my part. I was testing this in `main.swift` where you can use the Application in the same fashion as it's also a container.

Answer (score 2):

`HTTPClient.connect` returns `Future<HTTPClient>` and it is mapping to a `Future<HTTPResponse>` not a `EventLoopFuture<HTTPResponse>`.

If you're expecting a single `HTTPResponse` use `HttpClient.send` instead of `HTTPClient.connect`.

If you're expecting multiple `HTTPResponse`s then `.map(to: HTTPResponse.self)` must be changed to properly map to a `EventLoopFuture<HTTPResponse>`